# Multiply last column of table by vector and sum up values

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a function to multiply the last column by a vector that goes from 1 to 12, subtracting a half at each step, and then being divided by 12 and then add up all the values for the following dataset:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(0.984214961568032
), X2 = c(0.969939364667325
), X3 = c(0.918721423412424
), X4 = c(0.875639682899404
), X5 = c(0.845581970754608
), X6 = c(0.820781075047387
), X7 = c(0.799933411615345
), X8 = c(0.782229792539292
), X9 = c(0.766929352104221
), X10 = c(0.752818174197523
), X11 = c(0.738566265544561
), X12 = c(0.722809594554857
), Last_Column = c(169329.9)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried the code below below but got:

> ```
> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , last_column, value =  c(7055.4125, :
>  replacement has 12 rows, data has 3
> ```

```
multiply_last_column <- function(dataset) {
  vector2 <- ((1:12) - 0.5) / 12
  dataset_modified <- dataset
  last_column <- ncol(dataset_modified)
  dataset_modified[, last_column] <- dataset_modified[, last_column] * vector2
  return(dataset_modified)
}
print(vector2)
result2 <- multiply_last_column(pred_example_incr)
```

As an example, the desired output should be(approximately) 1,015,979, because we're taking the last column, multiplying it by(N - .5) and then dividing that by 12, and N is 1:12.

Comment: Your last column has 3 values. I don't know what you want when you say to divide 3 values by 12 values (and neither does R, hence the error). Let's take a simple example: If the last column was `c(1, 2, 3)`, what calculation would you want to do on those 3 values with the 12 values? Can you show us the desired result and explain it?

Comment: Made the amendments, sorry about that.

Comment: The last column, 169329, is all that matters in the context of this dataset.

Comment: Next time, I'd suggest editing your question down so it focuses only on what matters. No need to include `X1` to `X12` in the sample data - the only thing they add is potential confusion.

Comment: The error goes away if you actually give that last column in your example data 12 instead of 3 rows (replace`c(NA, -3L` by `c(NA, -12L)`). Then all that's left is the last step: `sum(result2$Last_Column)` does return `1015979`. Just need to plug that into the function instead of returning the whole modified data set.

Comment: @Where'smytowel I think the issue is that OP wants this operation applied with the whole 1:12 vector to every row, not 1 on the first row, 2 on the 2nd, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Last_Column = 169329.9
sum(Last_Column * ((1:12) - 0.5)) / 12
# [1] 1015974
```

Because this operation has vectors in it, it is not vectorized over `Last_Column`. If you want the do this operation to each value in `Last_Column` individually, use `sapply` like this:

```
Last_Column = 1:3
sapply(Last_Column, \(x) sum(x * ((1:12) - 0.5)) / 12)
# [1]  6 12 18
```

Or in a function:

```
multiply_last_column <- function(dataset) {
  vector2 <- ((1:12) - 0.5) / 12
  last_column <- ncol(dataset)
  dataset[[last_column]] <- sapply(dataset[[last_column]], \(x) sum(x * vector2))
  dataset
}

multiply_last_column(your_data)
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the 6-12-18 output, but how would I apply that to the dataset?

Comment: `your_data$Result = sapply(your_data$Last_Column, \(x) sum(x * ((1:12) - 0.5)) / 12)`

Comment: I edited to include a function example. I much prefer `[[` for extracting a single column - using `dataset[[col]]` is a bit safer than `dataset[, col]`, especially if you use any tidyverse and might end up with a tibble or a data frame as input.